# Constructing Circularly Referenced Tables

Tags: oracle, foreign-key

I'm attempting to construct two tables in Oracle, `A` and `B`; each of these tables reference each other. In my script, I have the foreign key constraints 'in-line' of the `create table` statements. Of course, both the `create table A` and `create table B` are failing  because neither table has been created yet.

Is it possible to keep the foreign key constraints in-line, or must they be added only after the table(s) have already been created by means of an `alter table` statement?

Comment: Why do you need such a setup?  Sounds terrible...

Comment: First create the tables with no constraints and then add the constraints.

Comment: If you post _why_ you want this, we may come up with a more RDBMS-friendly implementation.

Comment: @Isaac: You either follow the hard road that Phil shows (with the `deferred` and `deferrable` constraints) or redesign the tables to remove circular paths in FKs.

Comment: A common problem that leads to this (circular) design is the *"Something has many Items"* and every *"Something has a default (first, best, you name it) Item"*. If that's the case, see this similar question: [In SQL, is it OK for two tables to refer to each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446641/in-sql-is-it-ok-for-two-tables-to-refer-to-each-other/10458105#10458105)  and some approaches to dealing with it. (note that it is for MySQL, so only 3 lines are devoted to the deferrable constraints solution)

Answer (score 4):

You must add the foreign key constraints after the tables have been created, using: `alter table table_name add constraint constraint_name <constraint clause>;`

There is no other way.

Note that, due to your table design, you may have to create the constraints with the  `initially deferred deferrable` clause. This forces Oracle to defer constraint checking until `commit` time & may be necessary if you cannot use an `INSERT ALL` statement and need to insert dependant rows into the two tables with separate statements.